# preposition could be used after the word "resemble"? like "she resembles with her Mother"

Tags: grammar

Question 1. could we use "with" after the word"resemble".
like "she resembles with her Mother" or she resembles her mother.
Question 2. could we use "resemble" in Ing form? like
she is resembling her mother or she is resembling with her mother?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. **Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: You can say "she shares some features *with* her mother" but **resembles** takes a direct object:  {nominal} *resembles* {nominal}.  That car resembles a duck.

Answer (score 2):

No, resemble should never be followed by a preposition. No to Question 2 as well.

Comment: Correct but no vote. I think you should make it clear that in different contexts *resembling* is a perfectly good participle. *There were two children, one resembling the mother, and the other the father.*

Comment: "She resembles, in some ways, her mother.  But that dirty mouth is her father's."

Comment: +1.  The OP asked about "*is* resembling", not "resembling" alone. And HotLicks, your example is a concocted one since "in some ways" is a parenthetic, and not part of the verb phrase.

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if you explained **why** the answers to Question 1 and Question 2 are, respectively, "No, _resemble_ should never be followed by a preposition" and "No."